# How to solve error of define Synset in python

Tags: python-3.x

i face problem of syntax it show error name synset not define

code in python:

```
Synset('cookbook.n.01')
wordnet.synsets('cooking')[0].examples()
['cooking can be a great art', 'people are needed who have experiencein 
cookery', 'he left the preparation of meals to his wife']
syn.hypernyms()
wordnet.synsets(word)
[Synset('reference_book.n.01')]
syn.hypernyms()[0].hyponyms()
[Synset('annual.n.02'), Synset('atlas.n.02'), Synset('cookbook.n.01'),
Synset('directory.n.01'), Synset('encyclopedia.n.01'),
Synset('handbook.n.01'), Synset('instruction_book.n.01'),
Synset('source_book.n.01'), Synset('wordbook.n.01')]
syn.root_hypernyms()
[Synset('entity.n.01')]
```

comiling error in spyder

> File "C:/Users/atiqpc/Documents/spyder/firstprogram.py", line 68, in 
>    Synset('cookbook.n.01') NameError: name 'Synset' is not
>   defined

Comment: Well, it *isn't* defined.  There should at least be an `import` statement for whatever module `Synset` is supposed to come from.

Comment: it not working men

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code you seem to have copied both the input and output lines from an example online leading to this error.

The line `>>> wordnet.synsets('cookbook')[0]` gives the output of `Synset('cookbook.n.01')`

The rest of your lines in the code you posted follow the same format where you have a function in a line then you are showing the output without differentiating between them.

Also you cant use Synset by itself since you code has no idea what it is, it does know wordnet.synsets since you did import wordnet (I assume you did)
* I assume you have used from `nltk.corpus import wordnet` since you are using wordnet in other lines.